# Is there any cloud clipboard which allows copy pasting between windows laptop and ipad?

Tags: ipad, windows, copy-paste, ipados

The closest app which I find is ALT + c
https://altcopy.net/
but they only support between anderoid and windows and their ios app is in development

Comment: Curious - do you need copy/paste for multiple applications or is it just for sending browser links from one computer to another?

Comment: Mainly needed for copying text of pdf on my laptop and than pasting it on my iPad in goodnotes, as it is convenient to open pdf reader and note taking app separately on laptop and tablet rather than opening multitask on iPad due to small size of my iPad and goodnotes is not available on windows

Comment: Go with OneNote and OneDrive.  Not only does it sync across all drives, I can annotate PDFs in OneDrive and have it show up on all devices simultaneously.

Comment: @Allan  the problem with onenote with me is that once 5gb of one drive fill, you have to pay monthly for onedrive subscription in order to use onenote and I think paying one time for an app is better (like goodnotes) and in goodnotes we have option to use google drive which gives 15 gb of storage, plus one note don't have ruled/lined paper, I can write with my apple pencil on blank paper

Comment: With the exception of the storage allotment, OneNote does everything you described there.  When I did my pros/cons between Google and Microsoft...Microsoft won by a wide margin - even though in the beginning, they looked more expensive.

Comment: I have found somethibg,  but don't know how to install it on computer, can anyone please help https://github.com/coralw/share-clipboard also the app they have mentioned is not opening, it says the app is not available on your region, so can anyone upload the app somehow if they are able to download the app from appstore